# How to pass Request.QueryString to Url.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an url using the method:

```
Url.Action("action", "controller");
```

I like to pass the querystring for the current request into that url as well.
Something like the following (but it doesn't work):

```
Url.Action("action", "controller", Request.QueryString);
```

Converting the QueryString to routevalues is possible with the following extension:

```
    public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValues(this NameValueCollection queryString)
    {
        if (queryString.IsNull() || queryString.HasKeys() == false) return new RouteValueDictionary();

        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        foreach (string key in queryString.AllKeys)
            routeValues.Add(key, queryString[key]);

        return routeValues;
    }
```

With the extension method the following does work:

```
Url.Action("action", "controller", Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues());
```

Is there an other better way ?
Thx

Comment: This will throw an exception if a query string contains two key/values with the same key, which is always a possibility since someone can alter query strings in their browser

Comment: Thanks, this question is a really helpful answer! What is `querystring.IsNull()` though? Is it a custom extension? Becuase I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The extension method seems correct and is the way to go.

Answer (score 35):

If you want to easily be able to add additional route value parameters to your Url.Action, try this extension method (based on Linefeed's) which takes an anonymous object and returns a RouteValueCollection:

```
public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValues(this NameValueCollection col, Object obj)
{
    var values = new RouteValueDictionary(obj);
    if (col != null)
    {
        foreach (string key in col)
        {
            //values passed in object override those already in collection
            if (key != null && !values.ContainsKey(key)) values[key] = col[key];
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
Url.Action("action", "controller", Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues(new{ id=0 }));
```

Comment: The first line can be shortened to just `var values = new RouteValueDictionary(obj);`. Since `RouteValueDictionary(object)` accepts nulls (it instantiates an empty dictionary), the ternary is not necessary.

Comment: You also can make `obj` parameter as optional like this: `ToRouteValues(this NameValueCollection col, Object obj = null) `. Then if you want to send only querystring as route data, then you can use `ToRouteValues()` without parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution based on pwhe23's answer.
I wanted to keep query string parameters through POST requests (due to a Mvc.Grid) and use just a single action for HTTP GET. CRUD actions are handled by a single page and modal dialogs inside (for insert/update/delete).

So here's my Extension:

```
public static class MvcExtensions
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValues(this NameValueCollection col, Object obj = null)
    {
        var values = obj != null ? new RouteValueDictionary(obj) : new RouteValueDictionary();

        if (col == null) return values;

        foreach (string key in col)
        {
            //values passed in object are already in collection
            if (!values.ContainsKey(key)) values[key] = col[key];
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Usage in Controller (e.g. Edit action):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
    {
        // Some stuff
        return RedirectToAction("Index", Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues());
    }
```

Form for edit generated in View (modal dialog is used):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "SomeControllerName", Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues(), FormMethod.Post))
    {
        // Some stuff... e.g. dialog content
    }
```