# Appending ?param= to mvc routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Some MVC sites have querystring params appended to the route Url (of which I noticed StackOverflow does), such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java**?page=9802&sort=newest&pagesize=15**

What are the advantages of having the parameters as more conventional ?querystring params, rather than /param/values/ ?

Also, how are these params appended to routes that have been set up? I'm familiar with setting up mvc routes with params like "users/details/{id}" etc. but don't know how to configure routes for use with 1 or more ?params as per the example url above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query string parameters are useful when you have multiple optional parameters and don't want to include default values for non-specified parameters just to satisfy a path.

And you don't have to do anything special to include these parameters in a rendered URL.

Take the following route for example:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    "QuestionsTagged",
    "questions/tagged/{tag}",
    new { controller = "Questions", action = "Tagged" }
);
```

If you render a link to that route using:

```
Url.RouteUrl
(
    "QuestionsTagged",
    new
    {
        tag = "java",
        page = 9802,
        sort = "newest",
        pagesize = 15
    }
 )
```

...then the routing engine is smart enough to see that the route contains a parameter named `tag` and that the passed route values object also has something named `tag` so it uses that value in the route.

Any provided route values that *don't* have corresponding parameters in the route (`page`, `sort` and `pagesize` in this case) get tacked on as query string parameters. So the `Url.RouteUrl` call above would return `/questions/tagged/java?page=9802&sort=newest&pagesize=15`.

And your action method can explicitly list these parameters in its signature (promotes readability and maintainability) or you can access them via `Request.QueryString`.

```
public class QuestionsController : Controller
{
    // I can explicitly list the parameters in my signature and let routing do
    // its magic, like this...
    public ViewResult Tagged(string tag, int? page, int? pagesize)
    {
        // ...or I can grab parameters like this:
        string sort = Request.QueryString["sort"];

        return View();
    }
}
```

Note that the parameters to the action method do not have to match the parameters specified in the route. (In the route, I only specified `tag`, but the action method's signature lists `tag`, `page`, and `pagesize`.) However, any parameter of the action method that is not also a parameter of the route must be a reference or nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

I've normally seen paging and filtering data be passed as querystring parameters since it gives information to the user in the URI. It is also normally harmless if a user alters this data since it will just filter the data you see on the page.  Any sensitive data is normally posted so as it is not as easily seen or modified, but I would argue to keep your URI's clean and use quesrystrings  as little as possible.

You don't need to do anything special when specifying routes to be able to handle quesrystrings. They will just be extra data that is passed to your action. On your action you will need to do some work to handle the data though. Using your querystring above you will have to specify the querystring names as the parameter names and then whatever datatype you are expecting.

```
public ActionResult Index (int page, string sort, int pagesize)
```

In this example, page will be the value of 9802, sort will be "newest" and pagesize will be 15.

Comment: It's worth mentioning also that I've found in some cases that ValueType parameters need to be nullable to cater for the situation where they are not supplied (i.e. the input Url is 'clean') thus allowing defaults to be applied when null, as opposed to handling `0` values.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That all makes sense, I'm just wondering how you'd generate one of your routes 'and' append the trailing ?parameters onto the end of the route? Is there a helper method that accomodates this?

Comment: @Marc - You're looking for `Url.Action` and an example of one type of usage can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818065/how-to-pass-request-querystring-to-url-action