# Can you use Routes and Query String Values Together?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to use routing and query strings together?

An example would be the following as a route in my *Global.asax* file:

```
 void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
 {
      routes.MapPageRoute("My Route Name", "users/{UserName}", "~/users/UserInfo.aspx");
 }
```

Could I somehow use http://www.mywebsite.com/users/usernamehere?info=bla and pass info=bla to the page? I would rather not try to encode this in the route schema.

Comment: This SO article has information that seems helpful to your question:  [Appending ?param= to mvc routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995608/appending-param-to-mvc-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use routes and query string values together.  When you define a route, your route is not determined by the query string; rather, it's determined by your URL parts.

Check out this concise [article](http://forums.asp.net/p/1549452/3795116.aspx) about using routes and query strings -- Sanderson points out that you can easily use the two together.

And even though the referenced article is about MVC2, you can use routing with ASP.NET web forms.  I've used it before and it's not too hard to implement.

Comment: I tested it before and it failed. For some reason it works this time.