# How to construct URLs in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes

I am using `Url.RouteUrl` to create a URL to return to my user.

```
var path = Url.RouteUrl(new RouteValueDictionary()
            {
                { "controller", "Home"},
                {"action", "myaction"},
                {"area" , "myarea"},
            });
```

This returns me a nice URL with `myarea/home/myaction`

If I need to add an extra param to it, say like `myarea/home/myaction?param1=abc`, how can that be done ?

I tried

```
var param1Value = "abc";
var path = Url.RouteUrl(new RouteValueDictionary()
            {
                { "controller", "Home"},
                {"action", "myaction"},
                {"area" , "myarea"},
                new {param1 = param1Value },
            });
```

This seems like not the way to be.

Can any one suggest some way to do this ?

Comment: @KennethK.: can you post an example, if possible ?

Comment: Disregard my previous (deleted) comment. I read your code incorrectly.

Comment: Here's something similar to your request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995608/appending-param-to-mvc-routes

Comment: Here's Scott Guthrie's blog about Routes. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing

Comment: Nix the `new` (only "new") on last item in the dictionary, then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Url.Action("myAction","Home", new {area="myarea", param="paramvalue"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out an elegant way of doing this.

```
var myDesiredUrl = FetchDomainUri();

myDesiredUrl.Path = Url.RouteUrl(new RouteValueDictionary()
{
    { "controller", "Home" },
    { "action", "myAction" },
    { "area" , "myArea" },
});

myDesiredUrl.QueryString.Add("myParam1", param1Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
return (new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "Home",
                            action = "myAction",
                            area = "myArea"
                        })));
```

If you want to add a param to it, you may add/modify the route map in the Route Config file. Once the new key is added, the value can be specified in the above code.