# Pass json data to URL?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

current script:

```
var IrregularChartParams = InitializeChartParams();

// parametreleri json stringe cevir...
var chartParams = JSON.stringify(IrregularChartParams);

$.ajax({
    url: '/Widget/GridExportToExcel',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: chartParams,
    ....
```

Controller

```
public void GridExportToExcel(IrregularChartParams chartParams)
{
```

I want some thing like following:

```
// I know this does not work...
var url = '/Widget/GridExportToExcel' + chartParams
window.open(url);
```

What is the easy way to add json data to url with model binding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818065/how-to-pass-request-querystring-to-url-action

Comment: @Ravi, Im sorry I updated my question. I use seperate js file from razor. So I cant use "Ur.Action"

Comment: Seems to me that you really want to pass some parameters in the query string.  If you match the query string param names and the parameter names on your action method you'll get what you want.

Comment: @Jammer, So Should I write a function to convert params to an URL in a loop?

Comment: Why do you need to pass params as query string, while you are posting request? The action method will receive them. Could you explain more?

Comment: @Javad_Amiry, because I want to export an excel file. So when request is ajax, you cannot return excel file with $.ajax . I should use window.open to export excel. Check [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316415/asp-net-mvc-export-to-excel)

Comment: So you just need to change the request method `GET`. I'll write an answer, test it please and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I cant explain, but I found a solution, I dont know, it is the best, but it works

```
var IrregularChartParams = InitializeChartParams();
var url = '/Widget/GridExportToExcel?' + $.param(IrregularChartParams, true);
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

**1:**
If `InitializeChartParams()` function, returns a name-value pair, you do not need to any thing, but change the request method to `GET` :

```
var IrregularChartParams = InitializeChartParams();

// parametreleri json stringe cevir...
// var chartParams = JSON.stringify(IrregularChartParams);
var chartParams = IrregularChartParams; 

$.ajax({
    url: '/Widget/GridExportToExcel',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: chartParams,
    ....
```

**2:**
If `InitializeChartParams()` does not return a name-value collection, you can attach its content to the URL as query string, by `$.param`, as you mentioned in your answer.

**3:**
and if you want, you can pass the `IrregularChartParams` as a single query string item to the server, and deserialize it at server:

```
var IrregularChartParams = InitializeChartParams();

var chartParams = JSON.stringify(IrregularChartParams);

$.ajax({
    url: '/Widget/GridExportToExcel',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {sp: chartParams},

and action method:

public void GridExportToExcel(string cp) {
    var chartParams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IrregularChartParams>(json);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but there is no problem about passing json objects. My first code is doing that. $.ajax function is working, but exporting is not working. Because you cannot export an excel file with ajax request...

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi yep I do understand your point just now. You're right. The way you did, is good enough to work. +1 to your answer. Cheers